# How to set a time limit to an android activity

Tags: android, button, android-activity

I have a game where if a user touches the wrong button he goes to the highscores page and if he clicks the right one he goes to the next level. What I would like to do is make it so if the user does absolutely nothing for 1.5 seconds (fast-paced game) then it automatically intents him back to the scores.class activity. I am new to programming so anything helps!!! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you an idea:

```
private MainActivity context;
private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
public boolean timerStopped;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    context = this;

    startTimer();

    // method looks at users choice, example
    /* if (answer == true){
        stopTimer();
        // go to next question and start timer again..
     }
     else{
        // do something
     }
    */
}

/** Starts the timer **/
public void startTimer() {
    setTimerStartListener();
    timerStopped = false;
}

/** Stop the timer **/
public void stopTimer() {
    countDownTimer.cancel();
    timerStopped = true;
}

/** Timer method: CountDownTimer **/
private void setTimerStartListener() {
    // will be called at every 1500 milliseconds i.e. every 1.5 second.
    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(1500, 1500) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

        }

        public void onFinish() {
            // Here do what you like...
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, Scores.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Comment: How can I make it so that is they press the correct button the timer is canceled and then the code starts again for the next level. P.S I know you were the one who answered it so I'll give you the rep as soon as I figure it out

Comment: I just updated the answer to help anyone who experiences the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried with CountDownTimer?

Here is an example:

```
 new CountDownTimer(1500, 1500) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

        }

        public void onFinish() {
           // Here do what you like...
        }
    }.start();
```

Comment: When using the onFinish
         
public void onFinish() {
       Intent intent = new Intent(this, Scores.class);
       startActivity(intent);
         }
It throws up the following error:
The constructor Intent(new CountDownTimer(){}, Class<Scores>) is undefined

Answer (score 0):

To fix the error mentioned:

```
 MainActivity context;

@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    context = this;

    new CountDownTimer(1500, 1500) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

        }

        public void onFinish() {
            // Here do what you like...
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, Score.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }.start();
```